# Information box with cookie will be displayed all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, cookies

This is how when I click on my button so reload the page and I can remember look to box like "go away by itself when I clicked. But it sets no cookie on when I click and it checks also not up if it is set or not ?.

so the problem is right now:

- Cookie will not add
- Does not check up on the date we have today is 10 days more than the one we have with cookie in other words, to go 10 days before the show content again.

*I use the web form in asp.net*

**Html code here**

```
<div style="position: relative;" id="#CookieBox">
            <div class="alert alert-info fade in nomargin" style="margin: 0; position:fixed; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; height:65px; border-radius:0; z-index:10000;">
                <div class="container">
                    <p style="font-size:11px;">
                        Cookies er nødvendige for at få hjemmesiden til at fungere, men cookies giver også info om hvordan du bruger vores hjemmeside. og Cookies på denne hjemmeside bruges primært til trafikmåling
                        <button class="btn btn-info" id="AccepterCookie">Accepter</button>
                        <a href="../cookie/Cookies.pdf" target="_blank">Læs mere</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Jquery code here**

```
<script>
            var datoCookieValue = (new Date).setDate(10); //This cookie number of days

            //It must check in sf whether it is null or whether it is more than the 10 days that I have chosen.
            if (datoCookieValue == null || datoCookieValue >= (new Date).getDay)//checking up on whether the cookie is "set"
            {
                //when you click "Accept" so be content with cookie box contents go away
                $("#AccepterCookie").click(function () {
                    $("#CookieBox").slideDown("slow");//shuts down the cookie box.

                    //addcookie here
                    $.cookie("CookieAdd", 1, { expires: datoCookieValue });
                });
            }
            else
            {
                //must first show box on the 10 days it will look when the 
                //10 days are up then the display contents again.
                $("CookieBox").hide("fast");
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jquery you use sometimes #CookieBox and CookieBox selector. If condition where you check date in my opinion is not necessary, because cookie has a expiry time.

This is my solution:

```
<div style="position: relative; display:none" id="CookieBox">
            <div class="alert alert-info fade in nomargin" style="margin: 0; position:fixed; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; height:65px; border-radius:0; z-index:10000;">
                <div class="container">
                    <p style="font-size:11px;">
                        Cookies er nødvendige for at få hjemmesiden til at fungere, men cookies giver også info om hvordan du bruger vores hjemmeside. og Cookies på denne hjemmeside bruges primært til trafikmåling
                        <button class="btn btn-info" id="AccepterCookie">Accepter</button>
                        <a href="../cookie/Cookies.pdf" target="_blank">Læs mere</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
var datoCookieValue = $.cookie('CookieAdd');

  if (!datoCookieValue) {
      $("#CookieBox").show();

      $("#AccepterCookie").click(function() {
          $("#CookieBox").hide("slow");
          $.cookie("CookieAdd", 1, {
              expires: 10
          });
      });
  }
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cLtazsry/

Comment: after I tried your version from the link you have created, so it will not show on my own website, it has a meaning? or what?

Comment: CookieBox is default hidden and it will be visible when you don't have a cookie. If you have a cookie and you want show again you should remove cookie or run this example in other browser